# formarray first element display all the times

Tags: angular

I am implementing angular reactive forms form array in my angular app. I am using this example as a reference[example1](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-formarray-example-in-reactive-forms), [example2](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). I am able to load a new form array when add button clicked. I would like to know how can i display the first form array always and i want to only add the second form array on the button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the value when you're creating the form

```
    this.skillsForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      skills: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
          skill: '',
          exp: ''
        })])
    });
```

Or to follow the first example you can call do this:

```
    this.skillsForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      skills: this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.addSkills();
```